# Find correlation of two voice samples using python_speech_features

Tags: python, scipy, speech-recognition

This is for a simple automatic command and control system.
Commands will be sent over a noisy channel vocoded for voice signals.  Ordinary tones or DTMF will not work because the vocoder does not do well with tones or music etc. 
The transmitter will send a recording of the phrase.  At the receiving end I will have copies of the same recordings of all the possible phrases and I want to identify which phrase was sent.
My approach is to calculate the MFCC's of the received phrase using python_speech_features. Then compare them with stored MFCC's of the possible phrases.
I see how to do all of this except how to calculate a correlation between the received MFCC's and the stored ones. I want a confidence level of how close the two agree.
There must be some function in scipy to do such a thing.

Can someone please advise what direction to go with this?